# Keycloak : Failed to Obtain Policy Enforcer Error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

**Problem:**

I'm currently using Keycloak 15.0.1 with Spring Boot 2.7.15 within a Docker environment. Approximately six months ago, I successfully built the application, and it has been functioning as expected since then. I haven't made any changes to either the application or the Keycloak container. However, I now intend to add more functionality. When attempting to make various requests, including those to accessible endpoints, I encounter the same error consistently.

**Description of the Problem:**

Upon inspecting the Docker container logs for Keycloak, I noticed the following entry:
[docker container logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbh19.png)

The error I encounter when making any request is depicted below:

- [application logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u6Iy.png)
- [postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxiqk.png)
- [postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFS9T.png)

**What I Have Tried:**

I attempted to make the request directly from Postman to Keycloak and succeeded:
[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Ve0.png)

Additionally, I verified that the YAML configuration matches that of Keycloak, and it indeed matches:

```yaml
# spring config
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/JCRAM

# keycloak config
keycloak:
  cors: false
  cors-allowed-methods: POST, PUT, DELETE, GET
  cors-allowed-headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin
  realm: JCRAM
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8080/auth
  resource: JC-client
  ssl-required: external
  credentials:
    secret: #########################
  use-resource-role-mappings: true
  policy-enforcer-config:
    http-method-as-scope: true
    paths:
      - name: insecure Resource
        path: /auth/keycloak/*
        enforcement-mode: DISABLED
  security-constraints:
    - auth-roles:
        - "*"
      security-collections:
        - name:
          patterns:
            - /api/v1/*
            - /api/juriste/*
            - /api/all/*
```

**For additional configuration screenshots, please let me know, and I'll provide them.
**

Comment: [Keycloak adapters for Spring where deprecated in early 2022](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187). Also, in my opinion, offloading access control on the authorization-server (using policy enforcer) is a bad practice for several reasons: it adds latency (adds a request from the resource server to authorization server for each and every request), poorly scales (if your traffic grow, you can easily increase the number of stateless resource servers, for authorization server it is more complicated)

Comment: Plus it introduces tight coupling between your authorization server and all resource servers internal implementation for resources, you can hardly unit-test access control rules in your policy enforcer (this is trivial on a Spring resource server), it's hard to keep consistency of "policies" definitions across environments, and last you can hardly ensure that the policies in production at any time are those validated by the business.

Comment: All that to write that using Spring Security SpEL to define resources access rules not only reduces your dependency on Keycloak proprietary extensions, but also scales much better and is easier to test & maintain.